# How do you get the std::pair's first and second while creating a custom iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map, std-pair

I have create a simple HashMap (unordered_map) with basic implementations. Now, I wanted to create a simple custom forward iterator deriving from std::iterator. However, I am not able to figure out the implementation of iterator's first and second member like unordered_map's iterator. Can someone help me please ?
For simplicity, assume my HashMap has fixed 10 buckets and just using simple modulo to get to the index assuming that the elements would be integer type.
Below is the implementation of my HashMap and the iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

template<typename K, typename V>
class Node
{
public:
    K key;
    V val;
    Node *next;

    Node(K k, V v)
    {
        key = k; val = v; next = nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename K, typename V>
class Element
{
public:
    int count;
    Node<K, V> *head;
    Node<K, V> *tail;
    Element *next;

    Element()
    {
        count = 0;
        head = tail = nullptr;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename K, typename V>
class ForwardIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, std::pair<K, V>>
{
    Node<K, V> *itr;
    Element<K, V> *el;

public:
    explicit ForwardIterator(Node<K, V> *i, Element<K, V> *e) : itr(i), el(e) {}
    ForwardIterator() : itr(nullptr), el(nullptr) {}

    void swap(ForwardIterator& other)
    {
        std::swap(itr, other.itr);
        std::swap(el, other.el);
    }

    ForwardIterator& operator++()
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Out of bounds");
        if(itr->next == nullptr) // last node in the current index
        {
            while(el->next != nullptr)
            {
                el = el->next;
                if(el->head != nullptr) // if there is atleast one node at the current index
                {
                    itr = el->head;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    itr = nullptr;
            }
        }
        else
            itr = itr->next;

        return *this;
    }

    ForwardIterator operator++(int)
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Out of bounds");
        ForwardIterator tmp(*this);
        if(itr->next == nullptr) // last node in the current index
        {
            while(el->next != nullptr)
            {
                el = el->next;
                if(el->head != nullptr) // if there is atleast one node at the current index
                {
                    itr = el->head;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    itr = nullptr;
            }
        }
        else
            itr = itr->next;

        return tmp;
    }

    template<typename key, typename value>
    bool operator==(const ForwardIterator<key, value>& rhs) const
    {
        return itr == rhs.itr && el == rhs.el;
    }

    template<typename key, typename value>
    bool operator!=(const ForwardIterator<key, value>& rhs) const
    {
        return itr != rhs.itr || el != rhs.el;
    }

    std::pair<K, V>& operator* () const
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Out of bounds");
        return std::pair<K, V>(itr->key, itr->val);
    }

    std::pair<K, V>& operator-> () const
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Out of bounds");
        return std::pair<K, V>(itr->key, itr->val);
    }
};

template<typename K, typename V>
class MyHashMap
{
private:
    Element<K, V>* arr[10];
    int size;

public:
    typedef ForwardIterator<K, V> myIt;
    typedef ForwardIterator<const K, const V> cMyIt;

    MyHashMap()
    {
        size = 0;
        arr[0] = new Element<K, V>();
        for(int i=1; i<10; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = new Element<K, V>();
            arr[i-1]->next = arr[i];
        }
    }

    myIt begin()
    {
        if(size == 0)
        {
            myIt m(nullptr, nullptr);
            return m;
        }
        else
        {
            Element<K, V> *temp = arr[0];
            while(temp->head == nullptr)
                temp = temp->next;

            myIt m(temp->head, temp);
            return m;
        }
    }

    myIt end()
    {
        myIt m(nullptr, nullptr);
        return m;
    }

    std::pair<myIt, bool> insert(std::pair<K, V>& p)
    {
        int index = p.first%10;
        if(arr[index]->head == nullptr)
        {
            arr[index]->head = new Node<K, V>(p.first, p.second);
            arr[index]->tail = arr[index]->head;
            ++(arr[index]->count);
        }
        else
        {
            Node<K, V> *temp = new Node<K, V>(p.first, p.second);
            arr[index]->tail->next = temp;
            arr[index]->tail = temp;
            ++(arr[index]->count);
        }

        ++size;
        myIt m(arr[index]->tail, arr[index]);
        return std::pair<myIt, bool>(m, true);
    }

    myIt find(K k)
    {
        int index = k%10;
        Node<K, V> *temp = arr[index]->head;
        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            if(temp->key == k)
            {
                myIt m(temp, arr[index]);
                return m;
            }
            else
                temp = temp->next;
        }

        return end();
    }

    int remove(K k)
    {
        int index = k%10;
        Node<K, V> *temp = arr[index]->head;
        Node<K, V> *t2 = temp;
        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            if(temp->key == k)
            {
                if(arr[index]->count == 1)
                {
                    delete temp;
                    arr[index]->head = arr[index]->tail = nullptr;
                }
                else if(arr[index]->head == temp)
                {
                    arr[index]->head = arr[index]->head->next;
                    delete temp;
                }
                else if(arr[index]->tail == temp)
                {
                    delete temp;
                    t2->next = nullptr;
                    arr[index]->tail = t2;
                }
                else
                {
                    t2->next = temp->next;
                    delete temp;
                }
                --(arr[index]->count);
                --size;
                return 1;
            }   
            else
            {
                t2 = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    V &operator[](K k)
    {
        int index = k%10;
        Node<K, V> *temp = arr[index]->head;
        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            if(temp->key == k)
                return temp->value;
            else
                temp = temp->next;
        }

        exit(0);
    }   
};
```

Now, below is my main.

```
int main()
{
    MyHashMap<int, int> mhm;
    mhm.insert(std::pair<int, int>(1,1));
    mhm.insert(std::pair<int, int>(2,2));

    MyHashMap<int, int>::myIt it = mhm.begin();
    //std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl ->this line doesn't compile  

}
```

EDIT : The above mentioned code snippet is reverted to the original state which had issues. The issue is very clearly summed up by the answer by @"r3mus n0x" and also pointed out by @Evg in the comment. After making the changes as suggested, its working as expected. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: @krizajb Sorry for the confusion. Its a very basic implementation of hashmap (linked list chaining method) with 10 buckets and each bucket can have many nodes. Not concerned about load factor as of now as intention is learn about iterators. I have also implemented a custom forward iterator but can't seem to figure out the behavior similar to unordered_map's iterator where one can use the first and second member of pair to get the key and value. It might seem very trivial to someone else with experience with iterators but since I am new to it so looking for some help.

Comment: Your `std::pair<K, V>& operator* () const` is meaningless because it returns a dangling reference. You should have `std::pair` somewhere in your hash map if you want to return a reference to it. Take a look at how `std::unordered_map` is implemented.

Comment: @Evg Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I have updated the code snippet which is working as expected now.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I didn't scroll down and saw only Node and Element class! Please ignore my pessimistic comment! Sorry again.

Comment: If you want to show your solution, you can add **new** code to your question. But please **don't** update the original code in your question, because then the answer no longer makes any sense for other readers.

Comment: @Evg Done. Reverted to original state which had issues.

Comment: Thanks. (the comment is too short otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with your `->` operator:

```
std::pair<K, V>& operator-> () const
{
    assert(itr != nullptr & "Out of bounds");
    return std::pair<K, V>(itr->key, itr->value);
}
```

1. The `->` operator should return a pointer, not a reference.
2. You return a reference to a temporary object (same problem with your `*` operator).

Your current iterator implementation **generates** elements rather than points to them. This is acceptable in some cases but you won't be able to implement `->` operator since it should return a pointer that points to an existing value, not the temporary.

The easiest way to solve this is to actually store a `pair` in your map's node:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class Node
{
public:
    std::pair<K, V> value;
}
```

And then implement your `->` operator like this:

```
std::pair<K, V>* operator-> () const
{
    assert(itr != nullptr & "Out of bounds");
    return &itr->value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help :) Its working as expected now. I have updated the implementation in my original post.